# Excel VBA: Can't get a match, error "Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class"

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

For the love of all that is good, I cannot seem to get this to work. I keep getting the error mentioned above.

I have this table, and I'm trying to find out whether the code matches it's own sub-code somewhere within the other column, however it's erroring out. Your help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
Sub testing()

    Dim m1 As long
    Dim myrange As Range

    Set myrange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B23")

    For e = 2 To 23
        m1= Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(e, 1).Value, myrange, 0)

        If m1 > 0 Then
            Cells(e, 3).Value = "Yes"
        Else
            Cells(e, 3).Value = "No"
        End If
    Next e

MsgBox "Complete!"

End Sub
```

Comment: David's answer is correct, but why not just put the formula in column C?

Comment: Hi Doug, I will need to use this in conjunction with other functions that I'd like to do later on, which I can only be done optimally via VBA code.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the `Application.Match` function which allows for better ability to trap errors. When using the `WorksheetFunction.Match`, when a match is not found, it returns an error, which is what you're experiencing.

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match(Cells(e, 1).Value, myrange, 0)) Then
    'Do stuff when the match is found
    Cells(e, 3).Value = "Yes"
Else:
    Cells(e, 3).Value = "No"
End If
```

You could also potentially use the `CountIf` function:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myRange, Cells(e,1).Value) > 0 Then
    Cells(e,3).Value = "Yes"
Else:
    Cells(e,3).Value = "No"
End If
```

Neither of these approaches requires you to use the `m1` variable, you can assign this variable within the `True` part of the `If/Then` statement, if you need to identify *where* the match is found.

Comment: Quick question though: What if you wanted to "match" part of the value within the cell, what function would you use?

Comment: It depends how complicated of a partial match. It might be something simple, for example to count the occurences of any cell beginning with "steve", the second argument in the `CountIf` function would be like `"steve*`", or if you were looking for any cell that contains the word "steve", you could use `"*steve*"`, etc.  More complicated, and you might want to look in to using Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Just as another option, this can also be done by putting the formula below in cell C2, and dragging it down to C23.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$23,B2)>=1,"YES","NO")
```

Comment: +1, this is the way to go, unless there's some compelling reason for VBA.

Comment: Attempting to find a match to use in part with another set of codes.