# Finding and counting number of duplicates

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with a column called NumberID that has about 50k records. I am aware that there are duplicates however with scrolling up/down it takes forever to find anything plus often times excel is being somewhat slow. I'm trying to write a quick snippet of code to be able to find and count the number of duplicates.

I'm trying to write a quick way of doing it, basically my data is from rows 20 to 48210 and I'm trying to find a number total duplicate records.

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim matchFoundIndex As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
Dim count As Long
count = 0
lastRow = Range("B48210").End(xlUp).Row
For iCntr = 1 To lastRow
    If Cells(iCntr, 1) <> "" Then
       matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 1), Range("B20:B" & lastRow), 0)
        If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
     End If
Next

MsgBox count
```

Here im getting an error on = WorkSheetFunction.Match - i found that this property can be used to accomplish what I'm trying to do. The error says

> Unable to get the match property for the worksheetfunction class.

Someone have an idea? My vba has been rusty

Comment: If your only problem is that matching error, this may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751443/excel-vba-cant-get-a-match-error-unable-to-get-the-match-property-of-the-wor

Comment: @TJRockefeller - does the code look sound otherwise

Comment: everything you show you are using column B, but your reference in the first criterion of the match is using column A.  I would suggest changing both `Cells(iCntr, 1)` to `Cells(iCntr, 2)`

Comment: @Bobski I'm not sure what you are saying in that last comment, but yes the use case is different, but the answer to the question that I put a link I think is essentially the answer that you are looking for. You need to use Application.Match so that you can handle cases where a match is not found.

Comment: I don't kno how ot incorporate it into my code - the question shows a solution to a same problem but different scenario

Comment: Now it's showing me 19 as LASTROW but it's supposed to be 48210 ahhhhhh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you want to *"count the number of duplicates"*, a *very* fast way of doing that is exploiting [`RemoveDuplicates()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823(v=office.15).aspx) method of `Range` object, like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim helperCol As Range
    Dim count As Long

    With Worksheets("IDs") '<--| reference your relevant sheet (change "IDs" to youtr actual sheet name)
        Set helperCol = .UsedRange.Resize(, 1).Offset(, .UsedRange.Columns.count) '<--| set a "helper" range where to store unique identifiers
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<-- reference "IDs" column from row 1 (header) to last not empty cell
            helperCol.Value = .Value '<--| copy identifiers to "helper" range
            helperCol.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes '<--| remove duplicates in copied identifiers
            count = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).count - helperCol.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).count '<--| count duplicates as the difference between original IDs number and unique ones
        End With
        helperCol.ClearContents '<--| clear "helper" range
    End With
    MsgBox count & " duplicates"
End Sub
```

Comment: @Bobski, did you try this?

Comment: yes it gave me a very big number something in the 96k range - i think it took count of all the records * 2

Comment: Well,I had tested it with some 50k rows in column A with a predefined number of duplicates (just repeated many times a 10 cell pattern) and it worked. Try stepping through code and see what gets done in the worksheet along with querying immediate window (?helperCol.Address. Or ?helperCol.Count) .

Answer (score 3):

Using `Match` for this is incredibly inefficient that many rows. I'd fill a `Dictionary` with found items and just test to see if you've seen them before:

```
'Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.
Public Sub DupCount()
    Dim count As Long
    With New Scripting.Dictionary
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = Range("B48210").End(xlUp).Row
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            Dim test As Variant
            test = Cells(i, 2).Value
            If IsError(test) Then
            ElseIf test <> vbNullString Then
                If .Exists(test) Then
                    count = count + 1
                Else
                    .Add test, vbNull
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox count
End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason lastrow =19 but there are a lot of rows the data actually starts at row 20 and goes to 48210

Comment: @Bobski - `Range` and `Cells` are unqualified in this example.  If you're running this from a module they may not be referring to the correct worksheet, so you should fully qualify them.  Otherwise, see [Error in finding last used cell in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11169445/4088852).

Answer (score 2):

You can use my [Duplicate Masteer addin](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=5D1B99F93ACE3CA1&id=5D1B99F93ACE3CA1!122) to do this.

It offers a fast array method to deal with duplicates.

- **counting**
- deleting
- selecting

It goes beyond the built-in features of Excel as it allows duplicate matching on a

1. case insentitive basis
2. ignoring whitespace
3. even `RegexP` matching
4. runs over multiple sheets

[image]