# VBA Function returning #VALUE when called within excel

Tags: vba, function

Below is a function that is supposed to return a random value between `1 and 10` that is not already in `column A`. It works fine in terms of finding the random value and exiting the loop but in excel when called using `=Ang()` the function returns `#Value!` as below.

```
Function Ang()
  i = 0
  Do
   i = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10)
   Ang = i
   MsgBox Ang
  Loop While Application.WorksheetFunction.IfNa(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(i, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A"), 0), 0)
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: remove the msgbox line

Comment: @PatrickHonorez While that is a sound advice that I second, it is not the source of the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA: Can't get a match, error “Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17751443/11683)

Comment: does it work when called from the debug window ?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. The issue was indeed the Match Function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is WorksheetFunction.Match will stop the code with an error if it is not found.

Use `Application.Match` instead:

```
Function Ang() as Long
  Dim i as Long
  i = 0
  Do
   i = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10)
   Ang = i
   MsgBox Ang
  Loop While Not IsError(Application.Match(i, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A"), 0))
End Function
```

---

Or

```
Function Ang()
  i = 0
  Do

   i = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10)
   Ang = i
   MsgBox Ang
  Loop While Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A"), i)
End Function
```

Comment: Super man. That was quick. Many thanks. How do we figure out that Match function will stop the code with an error? Is there a manual?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hard-wiring in the range of numbers to avoid, why not make it an argument to the function?

```
Function NewRandom(R As Range, a As Long, b As Long) As Variant
    'returns a random number in a,b which isn't in range R
    Dim i As Long, k As Long, rand As Long
    Dim c As Range
    Dim avoid As Variant
    Dim count As Long

    ReDim avoid(a To b) As Boolean
    For Each c In R.Cells
        k = c.Value
        If a <= k And k <= b Then
            avoid(k) = True
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next c

    If count = b - a + 1 Then 'error condition!
        NewRandom = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    Else
        Do
            rand = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(a, b)
        Loop While avoid(rand)
        NewRandom = rand
    End If
End Function
```

Used like:

[image]

The function guards against an infinite loop. If in B1 I used `=NewRandom(A1:A7,1,5)` then the error `#VALUE!` would be returned. The code assumes that the range from `a` to `b` is not so large as to be a significant memory drain. If it is, then the array `avoid` can be replaced by a dictionary.

Comment: Nice ! Thanks for this.