# Filter by column name all sheets macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to filter the same column called "Location" from all sheets in the Workbook. The filter will be the same, in this case, selecting: "ABM", "AKH" & "ACH".
The column is not on the same position in the all the sheets.

I've tried combining some codes I've found on google and that worked separately. But when combined, it only works for one sheet. I'm thinking it has something to do with the "For" that stops.

```
Sub AllSheetsAutofilter()
    Dim p As Integer, q As Integer
    p = Worksheets.Count
    Dim i As Integer, rngData As Range

    For q = 1 To p
        With Worksheets(q)
            Set rngData = Range("A1")
            i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Location", Range("A1:AZ1"), 0)
            rngData.AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:=Array("ABM", "AC8", "AKH", "ACH", "AC4"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End With
    Next q
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set rngData = .Range("A1")`. You need the period in front of `Range`, otherwise you are not referencing `Worksheets(q)` in the `With` block.

Comment: Same for the `Range("A1:AZ1")` on the next line.

Comment: Wow! it did worked! thanks a lot BigBen. One more thing, I do get the error "Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class". I think it is because some of the sheets doesn't have the data searched. How do you stop this error from appearing? Thanks again!

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751443/excel-vba-cant-get-a-match-error-unable-to-get-the-match-property-of-the-wor)

Answer (score 1):

You were close.  This works for me:

```
Sub AllSheetsAutofilter()

    Dim p As Long, q As Long
    p = Worksheets.Count
    Dim i As Long, rngData As Range

    For q = 1 To p
        With Worksheets(q)
            Set rngData = .Cells
            i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Location", .Range("A1:AZ1"), 0)
            rngData.AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:=Array("ABM", "AC8", "AKH", "ACH", "AC4"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End With
    Next q

End Sub
```

Note the use of `Long` and the use of qualified variables.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the response. When running your code I do get the error "Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class". Why does this happens?

Comment: @AdolfoRangel  That error will occur if one or more worksheets do not have a cell in the top row containing **Location**

Comment: Declare i as variant not as long so as to handle the error. And before the `rngData.AutoFilter` add `If Not IsError(i) Then`