# If duplicate value found between sheets, copy and paste 'interior fill'

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that copies the 'interior fill' from column A sheet 1, and pastes it to column A sheet 2. It's supposed to skip values that aren't matches (ie. if Row 2 of both sheets have different values it wont activate) but right now its just doing a straight copy.

```
 Sub copyCombinedFormat()
'TO BE ADDED IN
' this copies the format for matching values in combined to the weekly report

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim cl As Range
  Dim RowNum As Long
  Dim m As Variant
  
  Set m = Application.Match(cl.Value, Sheets("Weekly Report").Range("A:A"), 0)
  
  If Not IsError(m) Then
  
     For Each cl In Intersect(Sheets("Weekly Report").Range("A:A"), Sheets("Weekly Report").UsedRange)
        RowNum = 0
        RowNum = Application.Match(cl.Value, Sheets("Combined").Range("A:A"), 0)

        If RowNum <> 0 Then
           cl.Interior.color = Sheets("Combined").Range("A" & Application.Match(cl.Value, Sheets("Weekly Report").Range("A:A"), 0)).Interior.color
        End If
     Next cl
     
End If

  End Sub
```

Any input appreciated

Comment: Get rid of the `On Error Resume Next`. And use `IsError` and `Application.Match`, demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17751568/9245853).

Comment: Also, [use `Long`, not `Integer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long).

Comment: @BigBen Thanks, how would iserror fit in?

Comment: `Dim m As Variant`, `m = Application.Match(cl.Value, Sheets("2").Range("A:A"), 0)`, `If Not IsError(m) Then`. Basically if `m` isn't an error, then it's the row number.

Comment: @BigBen edited post to include updated code, think I my have issues with the flow

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments:

- Remove `On Error Resume Next`, that's hiding all errors.
- It may be easier to use `Application.Match` and `IsError`. Make sure that you assign the result to a `Variant` variable (here `rowNum`). If there is no match, `rowNum` will be an error value, so test with `IsError` before attempting to use `rowNum` with `Cells`.

```
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2")

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Weekly Report")
     Dim cl As Range
     For Each cl in Intersect(.Range("A:A"), .UsedRange)
         Dim rowNum As Variant
         rowNum = Application.Match(c.Value, ws2.Range("A:A"), 0)

         If Not IsError(rowNum) Then
             cl.Interior.Color = ws2.Cells(rowNum, "A").Interior.Color
         End If
     Next
End With
```