# Excel VBA: Unusual behavior searching through hidden values

Tags: excel, vba

foundCell is returning nothing when I call this code while rows40-82 are hidden. I expect it to return cells(74, "B").

Parameters:

- ws = rev-loc tab, a valid entry
- row = 77
- actName = "4100 · Per-pupil
  facility alloc"

In the immediate window:

- actString => Per-pupil facility alloc"
- actString = ws.cells(74, "B") => True

```vb
    Private Function GetAccountRange(ws As Worksheet, actName As String, row As Long) As Range
    Dim rowStart As Long, rowEnd As Long, colEnd As Long, actString As String
    Dim foundCell As Range
    
    actString = Right(actName, Len(actName) - InStr(actName, " " & Chr(183) & " ") - 2)
    Set foundCell = ws.Columns("B").Find(actString, after:=ws.Cells(row, "B"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
     LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
```

[image: Rev-Loc worksheet]

It should be returning cells(74, "B"). Alternatives:

- When I run the function with rows40-82 visible, it behaves as I would expect
- When I run the function passing in row 73, instead of 74, it behaves as I would expect

Thanks in advance!
Josh

Comment: Try one of the answers in [Perform a find on hidden cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297624/perform-a-find-on-hidden-cells).  It uses `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` or passes the values into an array to avoid the `Find` problem.

Comment: If the row where the respective string exists is larger than 74, you should use `SearchDirection:=xlNext` instead of `SearchDirection:=xlPrevious`. This is the searching direction after `ws.Cells(row, "B")` (not included in the searched range), to obtain **first occurrence of the respective string**. If more occurrences may be possible and you need all of them, you should use a loop (firstly memorize the first found cell address and condition the loop when it comes back to it).